# Default windows user for Apache & PHP

Tags: php, apache, permissions

Looking at the processes running for Windows XP it appears that Apache (httpd.exe) runs under the SYSTEM user. but I can't figure out what User is used for running PHP scripts. It's a basic installation using Xampp.

I am trying to set the correct permissions on a directory (i.e "Modifiy") so that a php script can create a txt file and then write to it.

If I were using IIS it would be something like "IIS_USER". What would be the equivalent **Apache User** for **Windows XP**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP scripts are run as Apache when PHP is an Apache module, so that means SYSTEM for PHP as well.

The equivalent "apache user" question is a bit misleading: IIS_USER only exists because the installer for IIS creates that account. You could create a new user account with any name yourself and arrange for `httpd` to run as that user (be careful to give enough permissions).