# Accessing a file server (mapped) built in IIS 7 from a localhost in the same network

Tags: php, iis-7, localhost

I have a web application developed in a local PC in Windows using

- **PHP 5.4.25**
- **Apache 2.4.7**
- **XAMPP 1.8.2**

Now I want some files to be copied from a file server built in IIS 7 which is in the same network.

IIS 7 listens at random port number starting from 65000, other than this I have no idea how it was set up.

I have tried the following methods

- ftp_login() with proper username & password which has every rights
- copy('\\servername\folder\test.txt','path\to\my\folder')
- file_exists('\\servername\folder\test.txt')
- fopen('\\servername\folder\test.txt')
- opendir('\\servername\folder\')
- scandir('\\servername\folder\')

But PHP error says,  **`Permission denied or Access is denied.`** Sometimes it says, "The server has actively refused connection"

My question is what changes should I make in IIS 7 or in my web application.

I will answer any further questions on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out which user account is being used by Apache
   ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289133/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as-in-windows))
2. IIS may be unrelated, if you want Apache to have
   the same user permission as IIS, you can try to use IIS user
   [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245625/default-windows-user-for-apache-php)
3. After deciding on the account, give that user read access to that folder, both as sharing permission and file system level (NTFS) permission.

Comment: recommended reading on permissions
http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2011/02/04/share-permissions-and-ntfs-permissions-folder-access-control-amp-folder-permissions/

Comment: detailed: http://www.howtogeek.com/72718/how-to-understand-those-confusing-windows-7-fileshare-permissions/